# Struts validator validwhen (*this* == null) not working as expected

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, struts, struts-validation

I am trying to do some semi complex validation on a spring form using struts.

According to the struts user guide the value null in a validwhen clause tests for either an empty string or a null value.

I would therefore expect the following check to succeed only when when test is an empty string or null.

```
    <field property="test" depends="validwhen">
        <msg name="validwhen" key="error.test"/>
        <arg position="0" key="testForm.test"/>
        <var>
            <var-name>test</var-name>
            <var-value>(*this* == null)</var-value>
        </var>
    </field>
```

I am seeing that it works when the value of the input is empty. But if I delete the input from the form altogether (I assume this would then map to a null value), it fails...

Does anyone know how to use the struts validator to test for the absence of a field on a submitted form?

I am on Struts 1.3.8.

In case anyone wonders why I need to test for this, the end logic I am looking for is something like:

```
if(radio fieldA is present and true){
 fieldB is required
}else{
 fieldB not required
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if your radiofield really is null or if it brings some value as a blank string or true / false

Comment: Yeah, turned out the field on the form backing object was a boolean primative type, therefore could never be null!